# AngularJs Variable not displaying in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

For some reason my variable "navitem.route" isn't showing in the view when i try to use it as a param in a function. In the generated html the variable is displayed as "navitem.route" instead of the value of the variable, but when is use it in the href between those curly braces it displays like it should.

in my controller:

```
$scope.navitems = [
    {
        title: "Products",    
        route: "#/account/" + $window.sessionStorage.getItem('account') + "/products"
    },
    {
        title: "Settings",
        route: "#/account/" + $window.sessionStorage.getItem('account')
    }
];

$scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
    return viewLocation === $location.path();
};
```

In my view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="nav-item" data-ng-repeat="navitem in navitems">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{navitem.route}}" data-ng-class="{ active: isActive(navitem.route)}" >{{navitem.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The generated html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <!-- ngRepeat: navitem in navitems -->
    <li class="nav-item ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="navitem in navitems">
        <a class="nav-link ng-binding" href="#/account/2/products" data-ng-class="{ active: isActive(navitem.route)}">Products</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: navitem in navitems -->
    <li class="nav-item ng-scope" data-ng-repeat="navitem in navitems">
            <a class="nav-link ng-binding" href="#/account/2" data-ng-class="{ active: isActive(navitem.route)}">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: navitem in navitems -->
</ul>
```

How can I use "navitem.route" value in a function?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `navitem.route` will not populate on the view..but it will pass to the `isActive` function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navitem.route values starts with #. The url that location.path() returns will not have #. So isActive() will never return true. Remove the # from the routes.

Controller :

```
$scope.navitems = [
{
    title: "Products",    
    route: "/account/" + $window.sessionStorage.getItem('account') + "/products"
},
{
    title: "Settings",
    route: "/account/" + $window.sessionStorage.getItem('account')
}
];
```

In view use ngHref instead of href:

```
<a class="nav-link" ng-href="#/{{navitem.route}}" data-ng-class="{ active: isActive(navitem.route)}" >{{navitem.title}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ng-href, like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="nav-item" data-ng-repeat="navitem in navitems">
        <a class="nav-link" ng-href="{{navitem.route}}" data-ng-class="{ active: isActive(navitem.route)}" >{{navitem.title}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It results in     <a class="nav-link ng-binding" data-ng-href="navitem.route" data-ng-class="{ active: isActive(navitem.route)}" href="navitem.route">Products</a>

Comment: Sorry, like this: ng-href="{{navitem.route}}"

Comment: Ah... that makes sense :) Thanks!